# ajax request returning html, and not the actual value - PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using this simple `PHP` framework, after some upsets with others [Custom PHP](http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/11/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-1-introduction)

I have the following controller:

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct($action, $urlValues) {
        parent::__construct($action, $urlValues);
    }

    public function deploy_test() {
        echo json_encode("helloworld");
    }
}
?>
```

That function is activated by a `.js` function called `test()`:

```
function test()
{

    var data = {
        config   : $("#config").val(),
        machines : $("#machines").val(),
        test     : $("#test").val(),
        product  : $("#product").val(),
    };

    $.post('./index.php/test/deploy_test/', data, 
    function( answer ){
        create_bar();
        console.log( answer );
    });
}
```

However, what I get back is the `index.php` page, the `html` itself, not the `"helloworld"` string as expected. I have no idea what's going on. May someone please me?
The output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Deployer</title>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: post the return you are getting or a screenshot

Comment: Could the framework be spewing out boilerplate data around/instead of your output? I know CakePHP, for one, by default outputs a huge amount of CSS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the return type in your POST in JS:
`dataType: json`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the correct header information on the server side before sending `json_encode("helloworld")` so ajax can anticipate a json value before reading the answer. For example first lines could be :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); // no cache
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json'); // json type
```

You will also need, like David suggested, to add `dataType: json` in your ajax request.